# JavaScript. How can I parse a string of vars and turn it into an object with properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I am trying to parse a string in JS with a series of vars inline. The goal is to turn those vars into an object with name value pairs.

**Example:**

```
  var hwStr = "color=blue+coreCnt=4+shell=aluminum+wireless=false";
```

I know I can parse the original string to get an array of name value pairs like this:

```
varArr = hwStr.split("+");
```

When I print that array I would get:

```
>color=blue,
>coreCnt=4,
>shell=aluminum,
>wireless=false
```

In order to create this object manually it would look like:

```
var hwSpec = {color: 'blue', coreCnt: 4, shell: 'aluminum', wireless: false};
```

My question is, how can I use a foreach statement to create an object that would have these as name value pairs.

To be fair JS is not my language, but I know that I SHOULD know this... This is probably a noob Question, any help would be great.

Gary C  aka the UnKulMunki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you split the string at the `+` so you get an array of key/value pairs. 
Then, you loop through those pairs and split each pair at the `=` to separate the key from the value. Then you assign the key as a property name and the value as the property value.

```js
var hwStr = "color=blue+coreCnt=4+shell=aluminum+wireless=false";

// Split the string into an array of key/value pairs
var pairs = hwStr.split("+");

// Set up a new, empty object
var newObj = {};

// Loop through the key/value pairs array. The .forEach method takes
// a function as an argument that, itself, receives a value representing
// the current array item being iterated (a single key/value pair from 
// the array in this case).
pairs.forEach(function(pair){
   // Create a new property on the object with the key of the current pair
   // and a value of the value of the current pair.
   newObj[pair.split("=")[0]] = pair.split("=")[1];
});

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: I'm so sorry for those edits to your answer, I wanted to add a note to the end of my own answer but accidentally clicked on yours. (Because I was only adding at the end I didn't bother reading it vary carefully. Very embarrassed.) I've removed my note.

Comment: This is a cool, clean solution @Scott Marcos. very easy to follow. nnnnnn had a good solution as well but I was able to easily see where you were going with one glance.
Thank you for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

After splitting on the plus signs, you can [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the resulting array to process each `key=value` pair and add to an object:

```js
var hwStr = "color=blue+coreCnt=4+shell=aluminum+wireless=false";

var obj = hwStr.split("+").reduce(function(o, item) {
  item = item.split("=");
  o[item[0]] = item[1];
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

This is similar to using `.forEach()`, except instead of creating an empty object in a variable before calling `.forEach()` the empty object is passed as an argument to `.reduce()`. For this particular problem it doesn't make much difference, but in some cases `.reduce()` saves you having to create a temporary working variable.

EDIT: Note that my code creates all property values as strings - I don't think there's any way to know whether `false` should be treated as the boolean `false` or the string `"false"`, unless you want to assume that all values that *can* be parsed as boolean or number *should* be treated as boolean or number.

Comment: Solid answer @nnnnnn . I like the reduce method but I think Scott Marcos has a cleaner solution. 
Thank you for the quick response.
Gary C

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have to use JSON's parse  method to turn the string to javaScript object literal, this is how to do it:

```
var arr = hwStr.split("+");
var temp_arr = null;
var hwSpec = null;
var stringToConv = '{'; //string to convert to object literal

//iterate through the array
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  temp_arr = arr[i].split("=");
  stringToConv += '"' + temp_arr[0] + '":"' + temp_arr[1] + '"';

   //check if is the last string in the arr
   if (i === arr.length - 1){
     stringToConv +=  '}'
   }
   else { //add comma
     stringToConv += ",";
   }
 } 

 //convert to object using JSON
 hwSpec = JSON.parse(stringToConv);

 //your code here
```

Comment: *"you have to use JSON's parse method"* - You don't *have to*, that is just one one way to do it. But if you're going to convert to JSON, why not just use the string `.replace()` method, perhaps something like `JSON.parse('{"' + hwStr.replace(/=/g,'":"').replace(/\+/g,'","') + '"}')`?

Comment: @nnnnnn but, this method also work perfectly and is very fast.

Comment: Actually the code shown doesn't work, because it doesn't create valid JSON (you forgot to put quotes around the keys and values) and so `JSON.parse()` crashes.

Comment: @nnnnnn no need to put quotes around the keys and values in this scenario, since the arr array contains string "value=pair".

Comment: Try running the code from your answer and you'll see that it crashes.